# Flow for http request/response for a webserver with HttpCore

Tags: java, webserver, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to write a small webserver that accepts Http requests and returns Http responses in Java. I am using Apache HttpCore and specifically, I am looking at `HttpServerConnection` as the main interface to use in the flow of my webserver.
However, I couldn't find a usage example online. I see that there's a `receiveRequestHeader` method, but I'm not sure when I can use it (should I establish a connection first? Is a connection established during creation? Is this method blocking?).

Can you provide a short usage example for this class (the implementation I'm using is `DefaultHttpServerConnection`), or suggest a different methodology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) site has two simple http servers among the [examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html). One [blocking](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java), one [non-blocking](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpServer.java).